# El origen de la palabra "weón"

Tags: significado, origen

Estos días estoy preparando una exposición de la asignatura lexicología.Voy a hablar de la palabra weón XD. ¿Quién me pordría explicar cuál es el origen de la palabra? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Segun Wikcionario https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/we%C3%B3n

> Escritura rápida de huevón, por transcripción literal del modo como se pronuncia en Chile.